# Reading MATLAB-created netCDF-file with C-code gives wrong data

Tags: c++, matlab, netcdf

I have created a nc-file in MATLAB with the following properties:

- Format: netcdf4_classic
- Dimensions: xPx = 256, yPx = 256, polCoeff = 5
- Variables: IntLinCorr
- Size:       256x256x5
- Dimensions: xPx,yPx,polCoeff
- Datatype:   double

I have read the file in MATLAB and checked that it is correct.

Now I want to read the file with C++, using Microsoft Visual Studio 10. I have installed the netCDF 4.4.0 C library. This is my code snippet:

```
std::shared_ptr<CImg<double>> GUIModImag::doIntLinCorrection(std::shared_ptr<CImg<double>> image){
//image is an image of size 256x256 

// We are reading 3D data, a xPx x yPx x pNum grid. 
    static const int xPx = image->width(); //image width
    static const int yPx = image->height(); //image height
    static const int pNum = 5; //Number of coefficients from polynom fit
// This will be the netCDF ID for the file and data variable.
int nc_id, retval, var_id;

// Path of the used files
std::string fileName(QString("...."));

// This is the array we will read.
std::unique_ptr<double> dataIn(new double[xPx*yPx*pNum]);

// Open the file for read access (NC_NOWRITE)
if ((retval = nc_open(fileName.c_str(), NC_NOWRITE, &nc_id)))
    ERR(retval); // Makro for ERRORS

// Get the variable id of the data variable, based on its name
if ((retval = nc_inq_varid(nc_id, "IntLinCorr", &var_id)))
    ERR(retval);

// Read the data
if ((retval = nc_get_var_double(nc_id, var_id, &(dataIn.get()[0*0*0]))))
    ERR(retval);

// Work with data

double* p_FirstPixelImage = &(image->front());

for (int y=0; y<yPx; y++){
    for (int x=0; x<xPx; x++){

        *(p_FirstPixelImage+x+y)= dataIn.get()[x*y*0] * pow(*(p_FirstPixelImage+x+y),4)
                                + dataIn.get()[x*y*1] * pow(*(p_FirstPixelImage+x+y),3)
                                + dataIn.get()[x*y*2] * pow(*(p_FirstPixelImage+x+y),2)
                                + dataIn.get()[x*y*3] * pow(*(p_FirstPixelImage+x+y),1)
                                + dataIn.get()[x*y*4];
    }
}

return image;

// Close the file, freeing all resources. 
if ((retval = nc_close(nc_id)))
    ERR(retval);
```

}

In principle, the code works fine, no errors appear. However, the data I read with

```
dataIn.get()[x*y*0]
```

is not the same as the one I have written into the nc-file. In fact, the double values I read are in the range of e-20 while the data I have written is in the range of e-18 to e-0.

I guess that I might have a problem with the netCDF format.

Does anyone have ideas what I could do to correctly read the data?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why did you tag this as `C`?

Comment: As I am using a C library and their functions I thougt it would be more appropriate...